# ¿Por qué no me agarra el multiselec2 en hostinger?

Tags: php, html, hosting, localhost

Acabo de subir mi sitio a Hostiger.
Pero al querer ver si funciona correctamente, este no me permite hacer nada en donde los utilizo y lo demás del sitio sale bien. Solo es donde tengo los multiselect2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De manera local funciona perfectamente y los llamo mediante sus respectivo link y script.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Alguien sabe a que podría deberse esto?

Comment: A ciegas va a ser que no sabemos lo que te ocurre, la verdad. Por tu descripción suena a que el script no carga bien por lo que sea pero sin más pistas o código no lo podemos adivinar mejor. Suerte!

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Comment: De manera local si me muestra el select2, pero ya en la nube se pierde hasta el diseño.